# MySQL Failover error "Missing gtid_executed system variable"

Tags: mysql

I have done a GTID replication in MySQL 5.7.18, I have setup the fail over both master and slave health is good. When I am trying to down master I am getting this error.

> Failover starting in 'auto' mode...
>   2017-05-29 14:53:56 PM CRITICAL The server IP :3306 does not comply to the latest GTID feature support. Errors:
>       Missing gtid_executed system variable.

So I googled, they were telling to check global variable and variable which I don't understand. This is my master status of `gtid_exe`

```
mysql> show variables like '%**gtid_exe%'**;

+----------------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name                    | Value |
+----------------------------------+-------+
| gtid_executed_compression_period | 1000  |
+----------------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> show global variables like '%**gtid_exe%**';

+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                    | Value                                           |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| **gtid_executed**                | c6b90b56-4084-11e7-8af7-00163e4da2ba:1-26006378 |
| gtid_executed_compression_period | 1000                                            |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```